# Understanding what fc1000_softmax output from tensorflow CNN classification means

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am using python 3.6.10 and tensorflow 1.5 on a cpu. I have trained a cnn and saved it as a .onnx file. I am now trying to make a binary classification of my images using the code below:

```py
import onnx 
import warnings
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
onnx_model = onnx.load("trainednet.onnx")  # load onnx model
tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model) # Import the ONNX model to Tensorflow

img = Image.open('Im025.jpg').resize((224, 224))
img = array(img).reshape(1,3, 224,224)

classification = tf_rep.run(img)
print(classification)
```

The print(classification) gives me an output like this:

> Outputs(fc1000_softmax=array([[9.9967182e-01, 3.2823894e-04]], dtype=float32))

What does this output mean and how can I use it to understand what tensorflow classified my image as?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you have is the array of the output of the softmax layer of your model. This output can be interpreted as a probability assigned to each class ( in your case 2). You can also see it as "how confident the model is for each class".

So to have the final classification you need to take the max value of this array and map it to your label map { 0 -> class_one, 1-> class_two}.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the first number 9.9967182e-01 is the probability of it being class_one and the second number 3.2823894e-04 is the probability of it being class_two?

Comment: When I tested it on images of class 1 and of class 2, the first float in the list is always coming out to be significantly larger. I am confused on how I am supposed to classify the images.

Answer (score 0):

Yes exactly, so after you model is not perfect (ie the model doesn't have 100% of accuracy). You should test on more images of class two and you will see the second number will be higher .

You should run it on a test set or refer to the metrics of the trained model.

Comment: That does not make sense though. I programmed and trained the CNN in MATLAB, and when I tested the CNN on MATLAB I was getting around 95% accuracy. I then converted the trained CNN .mat file to ONNX and I am using it in python and on images it got correct on MATLAB it is getting incorrect on python. Why is that?